bazel cc_binary - how to use copts -I<label>
I'm looking for a way to provide a label as argument to a copts -I value and don't know, if this is even possible.
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["src/func.cxx"],
    hdrs = ["include/foo/func.h"],
    copts = ["-Ilibs/foo/include"], # This is the key part
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)

What I want is this
cc_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = ["src/func.cxx"],
    hdrs = ["include/foo/func.h"],
    copts = ["-I<bazel-label>"], # This is the key part
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)


At the risk of not answering the question, I think what you should do instead of explicitly adding the include path, is wrap the library you want to depend on in this rule in a cc_import, and then add it to the dependencies of foo. Bazel will take care of adding the necessary include path.
